# Please recommend Improvments to the SE Menu Structure

Tags: navigation, menu, design, contextual-menu

Over at [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) Meta we are haveing a discussion about the SE Menu Structure. Someone recommend we ask the Pro's over here for recommendations.

So, What could\Should be done to Improve the SE Menu Structure?

[What is the rational behind the P.SE menu system?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/what-is-the-rational-behind-the-p-se-menu-system)
[image]

Comment: I've found the invisible "active" tab a bit of an oddity at the least. I prefer the layout of the "invisible" tab the most though, with the column layout for views/votes/answers to the questions tab's layout, better for scanning.

Comment: @BenBrocka Agreed. This way is MUCH better for scanning. I never even view the other tabs, only the homepage "invisible" tab.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91661/main-navigation-questions-vs-home

Answer (score 1):

It's hard (and wrong) to redesign something without at least analytical data considering your users and your objectives.

I thought it might be fun so I give it a try, but please mind that I made many assumptions on what your site should do and where's the problem right now.

What I did is:

1) I separated high level pieces of content (questions, tags, badges, users, FAQ) from low level elements responsible for specific content-manipulation (sorting and filtering questions); there's one exclusion - 'Ask Question" button should be visible from every site of the service as a main functionality

2) I combined "search" and tags as two ways of quick browsing of content for people who are looking for specific topic

You can have a look on the project [here](http://app.uxpin.com/e313c43c0cfa5af02d7c95cc9a9dd5e24137cd7b/29319). If you wish to edit it let me know.

[image]

Comment: Added screenshot - we try and incorporate images into SE where possible, in case of [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Answer (score 0):

**I think 2 The two Menus should be Merged.**

1) Add `Hot`, `Week`, and `Month` to the `Questions Menu`

2) Remove the Redundant `Unanswered`

3) By Default go to the `Questions-> Active` option clearly showing it selected.

[image]

Comment: My concern about that is that *unanswered* is still really a subset of *Questions* rather than at the same level. Of course the problem being, that *Unanswered* has it's own set of tabs/filters/ordering/whateveryouwannacallthem...

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the part where the actual *content* on the front page isn't the same as the Questions list. Not just the selection of the questions excerpt, but all of the rest of the content as well.

Comment: Grace, what IS the default content, The consensus here is that it is the same as "Active". If its something different then that just stresses my point of how bad this is. I suggest Give that "Default Content" and Name and Add to the Questions Sub-Menu.

Comment: I see what you are saying.. The Whole side panel Changes....